# Preg_Split Group Multiple Delimiter as One Delimiter

Tags: php, regex

```
$var = "21.419603334153653%2c39.82548236846924";

$googleMap = preg_split('/[%2c]/', $var);
```

I need to have two parts:

1. `21.419603334153653`
2. `39.82548236846924`

The characters `%2c` form a single delimiter. Unfortunately, the second part gets messed up.

Is there any way to group %2c as one delimiter?

I tried `(%2c)` and `%2c`, they didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `/[%2c]/` means "any character that is a "%", a "2" or a "c".

If what you really want to do is split $var using "%2c" as a delimiter, why not use explode()?

```
$var_a = explode("%2c", $var);

print_r($var_a);
```

Comment: This was part of a larger split, i just didn't want to do it in two steps. Anyhow, for now i will with explode...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var = "21.419603334153653%2c39.82548236846924";
$googleMap = explode('%2c', $var);
print_r($googleMap)
?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21.419603334153653
    [1] => 39.82548236846924
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the explode() function does what you want:

```
$var = "21.419603334153653%2c39.82548236846924";
$googleMap = explode('%2c', $var);
var_dump($googleMap);
```